# How do I look up a Vertex using its ID?

Tags: giraph

I have a graph computation that passes 'visited' Vertex IDs around, and I need to output information from those in the output phase. How do I look up a Vertex from its ID? I found [Partition.getVertex()](https://giraph.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/giraph/partition/Partition.html#getVertex%28I%29), but IIUC there is no guarantee that an arbitrary Vertex will be in a particular partition. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can’t look simply up all the vertices. That’s why you have the computation phase to store all the necessary information inside the nodes so you can afterwards print them.

Doing it differently would to my knowledge completely screw up Giraph’s programming paradigm.

Comment: That's what I guessed. Thank you.